# Execute OrderBy with parameter

Tags: c#, list, linq, iqueryable

I'm creating a endpoint to retrieve some  data from my database, I'm trying to create a custom order by functionallity in my front end so I can call my endpoint with something like this:

> https://someapiurl/api/v1/controller/GetItems?ID=1&OrderBy=Name desc

And this is the code that I have in my endpoint:

```
//This is an example of how I populate my variable which works fine (I have the elements from the database). List is a Iqueryable<ModelName> object.
var list = dbContext.SomeEntity.FindAll...

//Code to get "Name" instead of "Name desc"
var param = orderByQueryString.Split(' ')[0];

if (orderByQueryString.Contains("asc"))
    return list.OrderBy(x => param);
else
    return list.OrderByDescending(x => param);
```

With both returns I'm getting my list in ascending order. But if I do the following code:

```
return list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Or

```
return list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
```

Both works fine so my question is, what can I do to have the orderby element dinamically in that code, because sometimes I'll send Name, sometimes Id or CreatedDate or something like that.

> Btw... I tried with list.OrderBy(param); but I got The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage error message.

Comment: I got could not be translated error message using the code from the answer in the duplicate question. I solve this using Linq.Dynamic nuget package. Now I'm able to cal OrderBy("param desc")

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
x => x.GetType().GetProperty(param).GetValue(x, null)
```

Comment: I tried your code but returns this error message: could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: Check this working example and compare to your implementation https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwYx6I